# run command on script in alphabetical order

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, sort, android, adb

I am trying to set the timestamp of a bunch of files on my android device using adb shell.

For one reason or another running touch with a specific provided timestamp does not work. In addition file globbing is not working on the android busybox shell using touch.

So I have resorted to a shell script that runs the touch command on all the files in a folder.

```
for file in `ls`; do touch "$file"; done
```

the problem it is not running the command in any specific order, when I want it run in reverse alphabetical order with the guarantee that it will be done serially such that a.png timestamp is always a later time than b.png.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are the file names all single characters with extensions? How would you sort a.png against aa.png? Could a solution include *only* alphabetically-named files?

Comment: You're running into limitations that have nothing to do with UNIX.  Have you considered asking on [android.se]?

Comment: What kind of file globbing *does* work in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use touch to set a time into the future.

```
T=$(date +%s)
for file in $(ls | sort -r); do
  touch -t $(date '+%Y%m%d%H%I.%S' --date="@$T") $file
  let T=$T+1
done
```

If you are missing `sort` on the device, make sure you have `busybox` installed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Yes, and no. Not with high performance. The sticking point is that you specify "a.png timestamp is always a *later* time than b.png", which I imagine relates to how some Makefile deals with them. Trouble arises if your filesystem only keeps CTIME stamp to one-second resolution. So I propose this:

```
for file in `ls | sort -r`; do touch "$file"; sleep 1; done
```

Yeah, I know, the `sleep` is pretty gross. But that's likely what you need to have `make` operate predictably.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am in the android adb shell, and it has a limited set of the command line functionality. Unfortunately I get this....." sort: not found". :(

Comment: You could ship `ls` results back to your host. Sort and iterate on the host, doing sleep 1 and issuing the various adb `touch` commands.

Comment: what about `ls -r` ?